# DaterangePicker and second click on same item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [Bootstrap Date Range Picker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) and I am trying to enable a second click on the same date range.

Ex: User clicks on "today" and gets results, then clicks again 5 minutes after and gets the updated results.

Everything works fine on the first click but due to line 298  `.on('click', 'li', $.proxy(this.clickRange, this))` the click gets unbound on that item.

I looked everywhere to try and correct it to no avail.

Comment: That line does not unbind anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback is only fired when a new date range is selected.

If you'd like to change the behavior, [this is the line to change](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker/blob/master/daterangepicker.js#L414).